# Создание файлов в сторонней (произвольной) директории

Tags: c++, fstream

Мне требуется создать файл в корне диска C:\ например, а файл находится на рабочем столе, допустим. Как реализовать?

Comment: Файл с программой находится на рабочем столе?

Answer (score 2):

Просто надо указать абсолютный путь

```
ofstream ofs("С:\\test.txt");
```

Comment: Спасибо, я думал особыми путями :-)

Comment: Тогда уж `C:\\test.txt`. Только, думаю, если файл в корне `C:` - начнутся проблемы с правами доступа...

Comment: @Harry спасибо за поправку, права доступа – уже отдельная проблема

Comment: @silantyev.daniil https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers